# docker containers need to be secure by default?

Tags: docker

Once the host OS has been penetrated is the docker container more or less vulnerable? And to what extent? Is there anything that can be done to make it more secure assuming that the default settings are weak?

Comment: Are you asking if the docker container is in any way secure from being messed with by a compromised root user on its host? No, of course not. And there is no way to protect it in that situation.

Comment: clearly if you can promote yourself to root then any data containers are vulnerable and container images that do not have any sort of 3rd party or 2-factor validation before execution. Maybe some kernel based signature checking, no docker client on the host only an API Server with crypto? Encrypted data volumes?

Comment: Root can play with containers even without a docker client installed (by using the underlying functions directly, or he can just install the docker client), any encrypted data volume that the container can decrypt is also visible to anyone with root on the machine.